# Append list to pandas DataFrame as new row with index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, series

Despite of the numerous stack overflow questions on appending data to a dataframe I could not really find an answer to the following.
I am looking for a straight forward solution to append a list as last row of a dataframe.
Imagine I have a simple dataframe:

```
 indexlist=['one']
 columnList=list('ABC')
 values=np.array([1,2,3])
 # take care, the values array is a 3x1 size array. 
 # row has to be 1x3 so we have to reshape it

values=values.reshape(1,3)
df3=pd.DataFrame(values,index=indexlist,columns=columnList)
print(df3)

     A  B  C
one  1  2  3
```

After some operations I get the following list:

```
listtwo=[4,5,6]
```

I want to append it at the end of the dataframe.
I change that list into a series:

```
oseries=pd.Series(listtwo)
print(type(oseries))
oseries.name="two"
```

now, this does not work:

```
df3.append(oseries)
```

since it gives:

```
A   B   C   0   1   2
one 1.0 2.0 3.0 NaN NaN NaN
two NaN NaN NaN 5.0 6.0 7.0
```

I would like to have the values under A B and C.

I also tried:

```
df3.append(oseries, columns=list('ABC'))  *** not working ***
df3.append(oseries, ignore_index=True)  *** working but wrong result
df3.append(oseries, ignore_index=False) *** working but wrong result

df3.loc[oseries.name]=oseries adds a row with NaN values
```

what I am looking for is
a) how can I add a list to a particular index name
b) how can I simple add a row of values out of a list even if I don't have a name for index (leave it empty)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either assign in-place with `loc`:

```
df.loc['two'] = [4, 5, 6]
# df.loc['two', :] = [4, 5, 6]
df
     A  B  C
one  1  2  3
two  4  5  6
```

Or, use `df.append` with the second argument being a `Series` object having appropriate index and name:

```
s = pd.Series(dict(zip(df.columns, [4, 5, 6])).rename('two'))
df2 = df.append(s)

df2
     A  B  C
one  1  2  3
two  4  5  6
```

---

If you are appending to a DataFrame without an index (i.e., having a numeric index), you can use `loc` after finding the max of the index and incrementing by 1:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(1,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df4

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3

df4.loc[df4.index.max() + 1, :] = [4, 5, 6]
df4
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

Or, using `append` with `ignore_index=True`:

```
df4.append(pd.Series(dict(zip(df4.columns, [4, 5, 6]))), ignore_index=True)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I am not using an index. Simply adding rows of data for later processing. Why is this not working:? 

df4=pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(1,3),columns=list('ABC'))

newlist=[5,6,7]

df4.append(newlist)

be aware the dataframe was created on purpose without index.

Comment: @Berlines Simply because `df4.append` was not intended to work with lists directly. If you are appending a single row, you must either supply a pd.Series object (which you did and noticed there was an issue aligning the columns), or use loc and assign in-place.

Comment: @Berlines Quite so.

Answer (score 0):

Without index

```
lst1 = [1,2,3]
lst2 = [4,5,6]
p1 = pd.DataFrame([lst1])
p2 = p1.append([lst2], ignore_index = True)
p2.columns = list('ABC')
p2

    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
```

With index

```
lst1 = [1,2,3]
lst2 = [4,5,6]
p1 = pd.DataFrame([lst1], index = ['one'], columns = list('ABC'))
p2 = p1.append(pd.DataFrame([lst2], index = ['two'], columns = list('ABC')))
p2

    A   B   C
one 1   2   3
two 4   5   6
```