# Why the function does not change the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to understand how to run a function that must take a data frame, append some rows and return the updated df.
I tried to make a copy of the original data frame, make the append operation and then return a new df as a result of the function.
However, this method does not work.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4],
                         "b":[5, 6, 7, 8]})
  

def append_function(d1):
    d2=d1.copy(deep=True)
    display(d2)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[12, 22, 33],
                        "b":[51, 62, 73]})

    d2.append(df2)
    display(d2)
    return d2

df3=append_function(df1)
display(df3)
```

[image]

The answer is always the content of the original data frame.

Can someone please give me an explanation about that?

Comment: Is it because you aren't assigning the result back to `df` after you call append? It does not operate in-place. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924656/df-append-is-not-appending-to-the-dataframe