# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append' for DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to create a DataFrame object for my spam classifier.It's supposed to contain two columns: 'messages' and 'class'. However when I use the `dataframe.append` function to add emails as 'messages' to my dataframe along with the folder name as 'class', I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

For this I initially created a Dataframe as follow
`data = DataFrame({'message': [], 'class': []})`

I tried to use the DataFrame.append() function for adding the spam and ham emails to the DataFrame. Here's the code I am using:

```
data = DataFrame({'message': [], 'class': []})

data = data.append(dataFrameFromDirectory('D:\email_classifier\spam', 'spam'))
data = data.append(dataFrameFromDirectory('D:\email_classifier\ham', 'ham'))
```

In theory, this should add the emails and the folder name to data.
Is there a way to get around this without having to use an older version of pandas?

Comment: use pd.concat instead

Comment: Actually, I see this question would be worth reopening and adding some information on exactly why the error occurs since presumably people will paste this attribute error into google and hit search and land up here.

Comment: See also: [Create a Pandas Dataframe by appending one row at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965)

Answer (score 7):

#### pandas >= 2.0: `append` has been removed, use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

`DataFrame.append` was deprecated in version 1.4 and removed from the pandas API entirely in version 2.0

See the docs on [Deprecations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#deprecations) as well as [this github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407) that originally proposed its deprecation.

The rationale for its removal was to discourage iteratively growing DataFrames in a loop (which is what people typically use `append` for). This is because `append` makes a new copy at each stage, resulting in quadratic complexity in memory.

In the absence of `append`, if your data is growing rowwise, the right approach is to accumulate it in a list of records (or list of DataFrames) and convert it to one big DataFrame at the end.

```
accumulator = []
for args in arg_list:
    accumulator.append(dataFrameFromDirectory(*args))

big_df = pd.concat(accumulator)
```

References:

- [df.append() is not appending to the DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924703/4909087)
- [Create a Pandas Dataframe by appending one row at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734983/4909087)